# How can I display the items in a list in java?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on project which involves receiving my mails from the gmail account, I am having no problems as such for getting the mails.  Now I am making a GUI which has buttons and a list. The list basically holds the emails received, similar to that in gmail. How can I put the mails received in the list? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a GUI list control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code sample may useful for you, if you wanna use JList

```
public class JListDemo extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    try {
        JListDemo frame = new JListDemo();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
});
}


public JListDemo() {
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 150, 303);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
setContentPane(contentPane);

JList list = new JList();
list.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "JList Demo", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
list.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
    String[] values = new String[] { "Google", "Yahoo", "Facebook ",
        "EBay" };

    public int getSize() {
    return values.length;
    }

    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return values[index];
    }
});
contentPane.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: hey you said, it helped you a lot, but how did this question get unaccepted. don't mind, just asking from curiosity...

Answer (score 2):

In `Swing` the data are associated with the widget's model. In your case you can use the `DefaultListModel` (I assume you are using a `JList`).
Example:

```
final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();  
final JList list = new JList(model);   
//add elements to model  
for(String subject:emailSubjects){  
   model.add(subject);  
}
```

Add them to the model to be displayed.
This code should be **only** in the EDT.